# Can an object tell Twig not to escape output when it is {{ printed }}

Tags: twig

I've got a situation where some variables sent to my Twig templates are plain old variables, so I want them to be html-escaped (as is the default behaviour). But other variables sent to my templates are really objects with __toString() renderers... and some of these objects send out raw HTML (e.g. from a WYSIWYG editor like TinyMCE or CKEditor).

Ideally I'd like for my template designers to not have to use the `|raw` filter on the objects, but instead somehow have the objects tell Twig that they're already escaped.

In other words, I'm trying to mimc the behavior of a Twig function that sets `is_safe`, but without requiring template designers to use a function.

E.g. I could write a Twig function using the `is_safe` parameter in its definition and be able to have this in my templates:

```
{{ figure_out_what_to_do(something) }}
```

(where the `figure_out_what_to_do` knows to inspect the "something" object to ascertain whether or not it needs to be escaped). BUT to me this is no better than having to remember to put `|raw` after every output of "something". So instead I'd like to be able to do this:

```
{{ something }}
```

...and have Twig recognize that `something` is an object and hence ask it whether or not it needs to be escaped.

I'm guessing the answer is "no", but figured I'd ask in case someone who knows more about Twig internals has any pointers for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `__toString()` method you could instead of return the html output, do this : `return new Twig_Markup($html, 'UTF-8');` thus marking it as a safe and not to be escaped

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for -- thanks! (Wish this had been in the documentation somewhere). FYI, I can't use it in `__toString()`, because PHP only allows actual strings (not objects) to be returned from that. But I can use some other means to work around this (like having a wrapper object with a magic `__get` method that twig will call, and it can decide whether to return a string or a Twig_Markup object).

Comment: @JordanLev, did you got it working? If so, could you please tell, how?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of returning a new `\Twig_Markup` object in `__toString()` (which causes a fatal error since it must return a string) you could extend `\Twig_Markup`:

```php
class Something extends \Twig_Markup {
  public function __toString() {
    return $this->safeValue;
  }
  public function count() {
    return mb_strlen($this->safeValue);
  }
}
```

Twig looks at the object to see if it is an instance of `\Twig_Markup` when deciding to escape the string or not. Here’s the source for `\Twig_Markup`:

```php
/*
 * This file is part of Twig.
 *
 * (c) Fabien Potencier
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace Twig;

/**
 * Marks a content as safe.
 *
 * @author Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
 */
class Markup implements \Countable
{
    protected $content;
    protected $charset;

    public function __construct($content, $charset)
    {
        $this->content = (string) $content;
        $this->charset = $charset;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    public function count()
    {
        return \function_exists('mb_get_info') ? mb_strlen($this->content, $this->charset) : \strlen($this->content);
    }
}

class_alias('Twig\Markup', 'Twig_Markup');
```

As you can see in the source code, `\Twig_Markup` implements `\Countable`. That’s why I’ve overridden the implementation of `public function count()` in my example.